# What does Spring Security's @EnableWebSecurity Annotation in specific do?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to understand the usecase of the `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation of Spring Securitiy's component. The problem I have here is, that I can't find anywhere specific information what this annotation does.

I want to understand which effects a manually set of this anotation has to

1. A standalone Spring Security application
2. A Spring Boot application with `spring-boot-starter-security` dependency on the classpath

**Ad 1)**
The information given at the [Spring Security Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/index.html) is almost null, you can barely find some scattered infos throughout the doc. The [Annotation Interface EnableWebSecurity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableWebSecurity.html)  itself only says where to add it. I don't want to guess around what it does besides restricting endpoint access to `authenticated()` by default.

**Ad 2)**
The information given at the [Spring Boot Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) is equal to null. Really, nothing, not a single word about it. Since I'm currently developing a Spring Boot application, and since almost all tutorials out there still apply `@EnableWebSecurity` to one of its configuration classes I'm desperate to know, what exactly this annotation does if I set it manually in comparison being set automatically through Spring's `SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration` class. When setting the annotation manually, SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration refuses to set it. So what further potential security configuration do I miss in this case?

I think the Spring documentations should explain specificly what `@EnableWebSecurity` does, how it interacts with personal settings, what it maybe has done in previous versions, whether its still best practice to set it in current versions and what side-effects can occur. An annotation with such a precence around in almost every Spring Security tutorial you can find should have earned at least a short documentation section for interested users.

Answer (score 1):

From the Javadoc:

> Add this annotation to an `@Configuration` class to have the Spring `Securityconfiguration` defined in any `WebSecurityConfigurer` or more likely by exposing a `SecurityFilterChain` bean

If you [browse the source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableWebSecurity.java), you'll find which other configuration it imports.

Note that this annotation is not required if you have one of Spring Security starters (like `spring-boot-starter-security`, `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` or `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`): Spring Boot declares it for you.

Comment: Yes, I have seen the imported classes which this annotation pulls. But as a framework user, do I really have to dig that deep into the framework's source code (which by the way is nothing but easy in an event driven or AOP designed framework) to get a grasp about something that important like `@EnableWebSecurity`? And even if I spend some hours to understand all the functionality that comes with that, I'm still not 100% convinced that my poorly development skills are sufficient to get all the magic which is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: I'd really appreciate it if the Spring developers would describe the main points and potential pitfalls of this functionality, so that I don't have to rely on my inferences alone.

Comment: Then maybe open a ticket asking for this specific documentation? Or maybe two tickets, actually: one in Spring Security for `@EnableWebSecurity` and another in Spring Boot for it's auto-configuration.

Answer (score -3):

The @EnableWebSecurity annotation is a fundamental annotation provided by Spring Security that is used to enable and configure Spring Security for a web application. It is typically applied to a configuration class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. This annotation plays a crucial role in setting up security features for web applications in the Spring Security framework.

1. Basic Web Security Config:

   @Configuration
   @EnableWebSecurity
   public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http
   .authorizeRequests()
   .antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
   .anyRequest().authenticated()
   .and()
   .formLogin()
   .loginPage("/login")
   .permitAll()
   .and()
   .logout()
   .permitAll();
   }

   @Override
   protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws
   Exception {
   auth
   .inMemoryAuthentication()
   .withUser("user").password("{noop}password").roles("USER")
   .and()
   .withUser("admin").password({noop}adminpassword").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
   }
   }

In this example, the @EnableWebSecurity annotation is used to enable Spring Security for the application. The SecurityConfig class extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, which allows you to customize security settings.

The configure(HttpSecurity http) method is used to configure security rules, such as URL-based access control, login and logout handling, and more.
The configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) method is used to configure authentication mechanisms. In this case, we're using in-memory authentication with two user accounts.
By using @EnableWebSecurity, you're telling Spring to apply security features to the application, and you can then further customize these features within the SecurityConfig class.

Keep in mind that this is just a basic example, and Spring Security provides a wide range of features and options to secure web applications, including support for custom authentication providers, OAuth2, JWT, and more. The @EnableWebSecurity annotation serves as the starting point for configuring security in a Spring-based web application.

Comment: `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` was deprecated in Spring Security 5 (Boot 2) and removed from Spring Security 6 (Boot 3). You should update your answer with references to `Security(Web)FilterChain` instead.